# Attempting to update an attribute within a User schema in MERN stack, but struggling to send the data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

For now, my test site is as follows:
First a user can register an account, after which they will be able to update their profile, since when registering, all they input is their email and password, so their name attribute is still an empty string.

My User model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    passwordHash: {type:String, required: true},
    firstName: {type:String, default:""},
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Other things like lastName, address, bio, etc will be easily added once I figure this issue out.

After registering, the user will have access to a simple form that allows them to enter a name to create a profile (for now, just the first name).

My CreateProfile.js file that I use as a React component is as follows:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function CreateProfile() {

    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");

    const {getLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    async function createProfile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const profileData = {
                firstName,
            };
            console.log(profileData)
            await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/auth/createProfile", profileData);
            await getLoggedIn();
            navigate("/");
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create your profile</h1>
            <form onSubmit={createProfile}>
                <input type="text" 
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                value={firstName} 
                />
                <button type="submit">Create Profile</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateProfile;
```

When the "Create Profile" button gets clicked, you get automatically rerouted back to the temporary "home page" via `navigate("/")`, a feature that does work correctly at the moment.
The `profileData` gets sent into the userRouter, who's relevant code is as follows:

```
router.post("/createProfile", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
            { $set: {firstName: req.body.firstName} },
            { new: false }
        );
        res.json(updatedUser);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});
```

And just to make sure I  handled my route setup correctly, here's my server-side index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");


dotenv.config();

//set up server

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port: ${PORT}`));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials: true,
}));

//remove the warning
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MDB_CONNECT, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

// set up routes
app.use("/auth", require("./routers/userRouter"));
```

And one more, here's the front end AuthContext.js to handle checking if the user is logged in:

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthContextProvider(props) {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(undefined);

    async function getLoggedIn() {
        const loggedInRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/auth/loggedIn");
        setLoggedIn(loggedInRes.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getLoggedIn();
    }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{loggedIn, getLoggedIn}}>
        {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthContext;
export {AuthContextProvider};
```

What did I do wrong that is preventing MongoDB from picking up the updated firstName? When I enter "test" in the form and click the submit button, the object does get created but doesn't go to MongoDB. What should I do instead, and is my problem in the userRouter or somewhere else?

[image: inspect element]

[image: mongoDB database]

I've been looking around online for previously asked questions similar to this and tried a few different things in my userRouter.js file, before I ended up with I currently have (that still doesn't work), to no avail.
Attempt 1:

```
router.post("/createProfile", async (req,res) => {
    var _id = req.body._id;
    console.log(_id);
    var profile = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
    }
    

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, req.body.firstName, {new:false}, function(
        err,
        profile
    ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(profile);
            console.log(_id);
            console.log(req.body.email);
            res.send(profile);
        }
    });
});
```

I've also tried instead doing `res.send(req.body.firstName)` which is pretty silly and obviously didn't work (if you couldn't already tell, I'm new to this).

I've also tried:

```
try {
        const profile = await User.create(req.body);
        console.log("success");
        res.send(profile);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log("err", error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
```

Which definitely did not work.

And finally,

```
try {
        const {firstName} = req.body;
        const test = User.updateOne(firstName);
        res.send(test);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
```

From other answers, I've seen things where people would do res.json() or res.send() or res.put() but I'm not sure which one I should be doing in my situation, though I doubt that's the root cause of my issue.

I'd appreciate any help, if you need any additional context or code I'll edit my post accordingly. My registration/login/logout stuff is working fine, I just can't for the life of me seem to create the post-registration profile creation functionality correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To update a document previously created you will need to add the `_id` in the body or in the path params of the route. So you will need to add some logic in the front-end to retrieve the logged user's id.

```js
// ... all imports

router.post('/createProfile', async (req, res) => {
  const {_id, firstName} = req.body;
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      {firstName: firstName},
      {new: true}, // "new: true" or "returnOriginal: false"
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The function `findByIdAndUpdate` need the id, the new values and optionally a options object (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate). "You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied".

You can also do this operation using `findOneAndUpdate`:

```js
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)},
  {$set: {firstName: req.body.firstName}},
  {new: true}
);
```

EDIT1:
In the front-end you will need to retrieve the logged user's id. I think that this data is inside the return of the "getLoggedIn" function which is called  You need to use your "loggedIn" data.

```js
// ... all imports

function CreateProfile() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const {
    loggedIn, // Get the "loggedIn" user data
    getLoggedIn
  } = useContext(AuthContext);

  async function createProfile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      /**
       * I think that the user is already logged in to fill the "first name",
       * the "getLoggedIn" was already called and "loggedIn" has some data inside. 
       */
      const id = loggedIn.id; 
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/createProfile', {
        id,
        firstName,
      });
      await getLoggedIn();
      navigate('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Create your profile</h1>
      <form onSubmit={createProfile}>
        <input
          type='text'
          placeholder='First Name'
          onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
          value={firstName}
        />
        <button type='submit'>Create Profile</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what kind of front-end logic I could implement? Sorry, a it new to all of this.

Comment: I also edited my post to show the AuthContext.js in case I need to make any changes there.

Comment: I've edited the answer "EDIT1" to include the recovering the `id` from the logged user and including in the request body. When the user login in the application you need to set the user data in the `loggedIn` state (calling `getLoggedIn()` for example).